# How to return values from a jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, get, jquery-1.9

How can I return some values from a plugin?

Here is my plugin,

```
(function($){

    $.fn.extend({ 

        get_authentication: function(options) {

     var defaults = {
                file:           'json.php',
                location:       'xfolder/',
                callback:       function(data) {}
            }

            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
            var o = options;
            var $this = this;
            var authentication = false; 

            $.get(http_root + o.file, function(data){

                // Send the data out from this plugin.
                if(data) {
                    options.callback(data);
                    authentication = true;
                    // alert(authentication); // --> get 'true'

                    return authentication; 
                }

                // Redirect if the date returns as 'expired'.
                if(data && data.error == 'expired') window.location = http_root + o.location;;

            },"json");
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

So, if I get the correct data as json format, I want the plugin can return 'true' automatically. and it also allow callback if I want to get into the json data.

on dom ready,

```
var data = $.fn.get_authentication();

alert(data); // --> returns 'undefined'
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return authentication after `$.get`:

```
$.get(http_root + o.file, function(data){
...
},"json");

return authentication;
```

Comment: thanks. tried it. it just returns `false` even if I get the correct data from ajax...

Comment: Sorry - answered too fast - ´$.get´ is a shorthand for the jQuery ´$.ajax´ function which runs asynchronous. So your script keeps running without waiting for the result of the ajax call. Thats why my answer returns ´false´even on success.

Comment: try using the ´$.ajax´function instead setting ´async´to ´false´:

Comment: ´$.ajax({ 
  dataType: "json",
  async: false,
  url: http_root + o.file,  
  success: function(data){
    ...
    authentication = true;
    ...
  }
});
return authentication;´